# What date formats are auto-detected on iPhone via UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent for calendar events?

Tags: iphone, ios

When you read an email on the iPhone containing a phrase like "thursday at 9pm" the iPhone makes this into a clickable link, allowing you to add a calendar event at that time.

Programatically, this is done using the [`UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) flag somewhere (so it appears).

My question is this: what time/date formats are supported by this detector? Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

To address "using the UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent flag somewhere": It applys to UITextView views, if you having editing turned off, and I have had better success if you tell it to detect types before you set the text value.

To address you format question: Yea.. I don't know if this is bug or what, but date dection seems wierd. I have it working seemingly randomly for dates using the exact same formatting.

This is the formatting I use, but like I said, sometimes it detects it and sometimes it doesn't.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

I have not found any documentation... probably because it uses some crazy heuristics that detects anything that "smells" like a date/time. I would think it would be flawless at detecting all the standard formatting options though, but no.